# Nash isometric embedding theorem with keeping the symplectic structures of our ambient spaces

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology, sg.symplectic-geometry

I apologize in advance if this question has an obvious answer.

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold.
Then the tangent bundle $TM$ carries a natural symplectic structure $\omega_g$. In fact  $\omega_g$ is  the  pull  back of the  canonical  symplectic  structure of the  cotangent bundle  via  the  obvious  diffeomorphism  between $TM$  and  $T^* M$ which is  defined by the inner product $g$.

The standard structure of $T\mathbb{R}^n=\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$ is denoted by $\omega$.

> For every Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, is there an isometric embedding $j$ of $M$ in some $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $j^*(\omega)=\omega_g?$

Comment: For the question as stated, I would have thought that the "naturality" implies $j^{\ast} \omega = \omega_{j^{\ast} \delta}$. Here $\delta$ is the Euclidean metric and $\omega = \omega_{\delta}$. Then the solution is simply that there exists an isometric embedding into some $\mathbb{R}^n$ since then $g = j^{\ast} \delta$.

Comment: @PaulBryan  may be I am missing some thing but the problem is that the symplectic structure originally  comes from cotangent bundle but the "cotangent bundle" is a contravariant (and not covariant) functor. Does realy your argument work?

Comment: I don't know if it works. It was jus a first guess. To be sure, can't you just check directly from the definitions? I suppose the answer depends on exactly what "natural" means here. Often in this sort of context where some tensor/form in DG is constructed from another, natural means "in some canonical way" but this may not be necessarily be the case here. I guess you construct $\omega_g$  by some lift of $g$ to $TM$ by splitting $TTM$ into $VM$ and $TM$ via the Levi Civita connection and the use a metric contraction of the canonical sympletic form on $T^{\ast}M$. Chase it through now and see.

Comment: @PaulBryan  $\omega_g$ is  constructed as  follows: the  metric  gives  a  dieffeomorphism between  $TM$  and  $T^* M$, on the other  hand  $T^*  M$ has  a  canonical  symplectic  structure (independent of any Riemannian  metric). We pull  back this  canonical  symplectic  structure via the  above mentioned  diffeomorphism. The  resulting structure is  denoted  by $\omega_g$. With such  construction, we have  the naturality property you  mentioned when we have DIFFEOMORPHISM  isometry  but I  am not  sure it  works  for  isometric  embedding(not necessarilly  surjective).

Comment: For an isometric  embedding  $j$  I  do  not  see why $j^*(\omega)=\omega_{j^*\delta}$?May  be the question is  obvious?

Comment: I see. Still seems plausible to me, perhaps naively. I'm in transit so I don't have time to check it properly right now sorry.

Comment: @PaulBryan  Ok, Have  a  nice  tripe.   The  naturality property you  mentioned is  amazing(and somehow  a  chalenging  question, at least  for  me). Any way  I thank you  for  your  attention to my question and  I look forward to hear from you about this  subject.

Comment: The isometric embedding and the introduction of $TM$ are probably a bit of red herring here. I think what you are asking is this: Given a Riemannian manifold $(N,h)$ and a Riemannian submanifold $(M,g)$, the musical isomorphisms allows you to define a a smooth map $\sigma: T^*M \to T^*N$. Your question is whether that the pull-back by $\sigma$ of the canonical symplectic structure on $T^*N$ is equal to the canonical symplectic structure on $T^*M$. Or, in other words, you are asking whether the embedding $\sigma$ makes $T^*M$ a symplectic submanifold of $T^*N$.

Comment: I hope I am not mistaken, but I think this then follows from the fact that embedded Riemannian submanifolds have normal tubular neighborhoods. This I think implies you have local coordinates $(x^1, \ldots, x^n)$ of $N$, inducing coordinates $(x^1, \ldots, x^n, y^1, \ldots, y^n)$ of $T^*N$, such that the embedding $\sigma$ sends $T^*M$ (locally) to the set $\{x^{m+1}= \cdots = x^{n} = y^{m+1} = \cdots =y^{n} = 0\}$.

Answer (score 8):

This is always the case (using "naturality" as Paul Bryan suggested in the comments).

Let $f: M \to N$ be a smooth map between Riemannian manifolds $(M,g)$ and $(N, h)$. Let $g^\flat: TM \to T^*M$ denote the musical isomorphism induced by $g$ (and similarly $h^\flat$).
Now, $f$ is an isometry if and only if $h_{f(m)} (T_m f (X), T_m f (\cdot)) = g_m (X, \cdot)$ holds for all $X \in T_m M$. In other words, $g^\flat (X) = f^* (h^\flat (T_m f(X)))$ or shorter $$g^\flat = T^* f \circ h^\flat \circ Tf,$$ where $T^*f: T^* N \to T^* M$ is the cotangent lift of $f$ (often called a point transformation).
Using the fact that cotangent lifts are always symplectic maps, we have
$$\omega_g = (g^\flat)^* \omega_M = (Tf)^* (h^\flat)^* \omega_N = (Tf)^* \omega_h,$$
where $\omega_M$ and $\omega_N$ denote the canonical symplectic forms on $T^* M$ and $T^* N$, respectively.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just a  question:  When f is not surjective how can one define "The cotangent lift", that is $T^*f$?

Comment: So  I  stil think that the  naturality property  mentioned  by @Paul  is  not  obvious(at least to me). am I  missing something?

Comment: @WillieWong  yes I  know  the definition of the  dual  map(In its linear  algebraic  setting. But  I  mean that it is  possible  that $f$ is  not  surjective. So  the  domain of  $T^* f$ is  not the  whole cotangent bundle  $T^*N$.

Comment: @AliTaghavi: ah, I see your point. But isn't that moot in this instance? You are looking at it acting on $h^\flat \circ Tf$ which would definitely have base point in the image of $f$. // Ah, I think I see your objection: you are wondering about "naturality" in this case.

Comment: This is why one usually defines natural operations only in the context of diffeomorphisms. But here, loosely speaking, naturality means that everything transforms as one would expect it to be the case.

Comment: @TobiasDiez  Yes the  naturality is  true  when we have  a  Diffeomorphism, but the  question concern embeding. it  would  be amazing if one find  a  Riemannian manifold  which  does not admit an embedding  in Euclidean space  which  preserve metric and  symplectic structure of  the Tangent bundle.

Comment: To be honest, I don't see the point of your objection. An embedding is a diffeomorphism onto its image; and the image is all you care about when you pull-back something...

Answer (score 2):

It seems here we have an answer: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0926224502000670

This is how I would approach the question:

The question is equivalent to the existence of some immersion $f : M \to \mathbb{R}^N$ such that if $\omega_{\mathbb{R}}$ is the sympletic form of $\mathbb{R}^N$ and $\omega$ is the sympletic form of $M$, one has $f^{\ast}(\omega_{\mathbb{R}}) = \omega.$

Note that since $d\omega_{\mathbb{R}} = 0$ and $\mathbb{R}^N$ is simply connected, there exists $\theta \in \Omega^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ such that $\omega_{\mathbb{R}} = d\theta.$ Therefore,
$$f^{\ast}(d\theta) = \omega.$$ Therefore, $d(f^{\ast}\theta) = \omega.$ This implies a necessary condition is that $\omega$ is exact. If $H_{dR}^2(M) = 0$, then $\omega = d\tilde \theta$, for $\tilde \theta \in \Omega^1(M)$. This implies that:

$$d(f^*(\theta)) = d\tilde \theta.$$ Therefore,
$$f^{\ast}(\theta) - \tilde \theta \in H_{dR}^1(M).$$ If we assume that this is zero, $f^{\ast}{\theta} = \tilde \theta$. Therefore, 
$$\tilde \theta (X) = \theta(df(X)), ~\forall X \in TM.$$ Note that $\theta = \langle Z,\cdot\rangle,$ for some vector field $Z \in T\mathbb{R}^N$. Therefore,
$$\theta(X) = \langle df(X),Z\rangle,$$
and this equations suggests an equation for the isommetric immersion.

Comment: OP’s 2-form $\omega_g$ is on $TM$ (not $M$) and is always exact.

Comment: Thank you for  introducing me the linked   paper. i will read your  answer  as soon as posible.

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler  Yes the 2 forms on TM are exact.  So there is no matter of exactness. The matter is whether the "Naturality" mentioned by Paul  is realy the case? What do you think about that?To be honnest I think that the problem is nontrivial.

Comment: You are both right, I misread the questions at first, so exactness is not a problem, but I endorse I am pretty sure that this is a not trivial question, this is why I have suggested one approach to at least look at an immersion equation. Also, on the paper I've sent you it discuss the problem on a more general frame, considering embbedings of symplectic space in to other symplectic spaces, not necessarily $\mathbb{R}^N.$

Comment: @L.F.Cavenaghi Thank you for your comment. The  linked paper is a very interesting paper.

Comment: @L.F.Cavenaghi  The point is that the natural symplectic structure comes from the cotangent bundle. On  the other hand when  $N$ is a submanifold of $M$, there is no a canonical embedding of $T^* N$ in $T^*M$ such that the embedding would be independemt of any metric.

Comment: @AliTaghavi, I see the problem and I agree with you that this is not trivial. Have you seen the paper I've sent to you? Perhaps one can obtain your desired result from there. I am so sorry for my naive approach, although it was fruithful to realize some properties for the immersion (as the equation I've stated). I agree that perhaps this is uselss to you, but who knows if it cannot be useful sometime?

Comment: Of  course your  answer  and  the linked paper is interesting. Thanks  for  your  attention to my question. You answer is not useless as i gave my +1.